# Windows Server 2016 patch - Docker Desktop Virtual disk is moved

Tags: windows-server-2016, docker-image, docker-desktop

After the installation of KB5020873 and KB5021235 patches onto a Server 2016 Standard all Docker Desktop images disappeared. Docker desktop was running ( I realise this configuration can no longer be updated - it's a legacy machine we are transitioning from) and the docker image command only reported a default docker image. All other images have disappeared.

A panicked reboot and inspection of docker desktop settings showed the location of the Virtual Hard Disk C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Virtual Hard Disks\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx. Upon inspection this disk was approx 100Mb in size. The expected size was some 90 gig.

Further investigations showed another Virtual Disk as located in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks which was sized around the expected 90 gig ( the worrying aspect was the Data modified was the exact time of the release update).

So the change was made to docker desktop settings to point to the 90 gig and os was restarted.

No docker images could be found. The VM had been repointed back to the 100 Mb disk.[image]

Answer (score 0):

We needed to copy the 90 gig from the old default location C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks to the new location shown above. This would then enable the images to be found. Repointing Docker Desktop would fail upon reboot-restart and revert to the "new" location. So we had to copy it across